# Consulta desde MySQL a SQLServer

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Buen día, necesito realizar una consulta desde mySQL a Sql Server.  Este es el escenario: tengo una aplicación en un servidor Linux que funciona con una base de datos en MySQL, hay una base de datos que corre sobre Windows Server 2008 con sql Server,  necesito traer los datos de una tabla de esas base de datos e insertarlos en una tabla de la base de datos MySQL.  Ya hice la conexión con ODBC Driver 5.3, y logré vincular los servidores, puedo hacer consultas desde el SQL Server con openQuery, la pregunta es: ¿es posible hacerlo en el caso contrario?, hacer consultas desde el Mysql a el SQL Server, es lo que necesito pero no he encontrado una manera.

Comment: podrías intentar hacer un script en php, que conecte a sql server con odbc, guardar los datos que necesites en un array, y luego insertar los registros en mysql

Comment: Ando trabajando con angular y java, nunca lo he mezclado con php, ¿habria problemas?.